# Improving performance of MySQL INSERT SELECT in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I need some advice regarding inserting a large number of records in a MySql database table. I am currently storing a large number of rows 90.000 from two tables to another table,it takes a long time.

This is my current code :

```js
  private void Merge_Tables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Delete records from exercices before inserting data.
            Delete_Records_Exercices();

            // Insert data from tables data and bilan to table exercices.
            string MergeTables = (@"INSERT INTO exercices (annee,AA,DL ,DO, DR ,DS  ,DT ,DU ,DV ,EH, ED, BK,CM, BJ ,CL,CN,EE ,AO ,AQ  ,AS1  ,AV  ,AW  ,AY ,AN ,AP  ,AR  ,AT ,AU,AX ,CJ  ,CH ,CK ,CI ,GR ,EC, 
EB 
  ,YS 
  ,FL 
  ,GU 
  ,FP 
  ,GA 
  ,GB 
  ,GC 
  ,GD 
  ,GM 
  ,GQ 
  ,HA 
  ,HE 
  ,HJ 
  ,HK 
  ,GW 
  ,DX 
  ,DY 
  ,DZ 
  ,EA 
  ,FM 
  ,FN 
  ,FS 
  ,FV 
  ,FU 
  ,FW 
  ,YP 
  ,FT 
  ,FY 
  ,FZ 
  ,FO 
  ,FX 
  ,BV 
  ,BX 
  ,BZ 
  ,CB 
  ,CD 
  ,CF 
  ,BW 
  ,BY1 
  ,CA 
  ,CC 
  ,CE 
  ,CG 
  ,DI 
  ,KC 
  ,KF 
  ,LP 
  ,MY 
  ,NC 
  ,CO 
  ,AB 
  ,AD 
  ,AF 
  ,AH 
  ,AJ 
  ,AL 
  ,FJ 
  ,BL 
  ,BN 
  ,BP 
  ,BR 
  ,BT 
  ,BO 
  ,BQ 
  ,BS 
  ,GE 
  ,DW 
  ,FC 
  ,HN 
  ,BM 
 ,secteur 
  ,NAF2 
  ,region 
  ,departement 
  ,siret 
  ,designation 
  ,effectif 
  ,chiffre_affaire 
,BU 
  ,YY 
  ,YZ 
  ,siren 
  ,AC 
  ,AE 
  ,AI 
  ,AK 
  ,AM 
  ,CS 
  ,CT 
  ,CU 
  ,CV 
  ,BB 
  ,BC 
  ,BD 
  ,BE 
  ,BF 
  ,BG 
  ,BH 
  ,BI 
  ,1A 
  ,GJ 
  ,DA 
  ,DC 
  ,EK 
  ,DD 
  ,DE 
  ,DF 
  ,B1 
,DG 
  ,EJ 
  ,DH 
  ,DJ 
  ,DK 
  ,DM 
  ,DN 
  ,DP 
  ,DQ 
  ,EI 
  ,FA 
  ,FB 
  ,FD 
  ,FE 
  ,FF 
  ,FG 
  ,FH 
  ,FI 
  ,FK 
  ,FQ 
  ,FR 
  ,FWbis 
  ,GF 
  ,GG 
  ,GH 
  ,GI 
  ,GJ1 
  ,GK 
  ,GL 
  ,GN 
  ,GO 
  ,GP 
  ,GS 
  ,GT 
  ,GV 
  ,HB 
  ,HC 
  ,HD 
  ,HF 
  ,HG 
  ,HH 
  ,HI 
  ,HL 
  ,HM 
  ,EQ 
  ,DB 
  ,AG 
  ,EB1 

) 
SELECT e1.annee,e1.AA,e1.DL ,e1.DO, e1.DR ,e1.DS,e1.DT,e1.DU ,e1.DV,e1.EH, e1.ED, e1.BK,e1.CM, e1.BJ,e1.CL,e1.CN,e1.EE ,e1.AO ,e1.AQ  ,e1.AS1 ,e1.AV ,e1.AW ,e1.AY ,e1.AN ,e1.AP  ,e1.AR  ,e1.AT ,e1.AU,e1.AX ,e1.CJ ,e1.CH ,e1.CK ,e1.CI ,e1.GR ,e1.EC,  

e1.EB 
  ,e1.YS 
  ,e1.FL 
  ,e1.GU 
  ,e1.FP 
  ,e1.GA 
  ,e1.GB 
  ,e1.GC 
  ,e1.GD 
  ,e1.GM 
  ,e1.GQ 
  ,e1.HA 
  ,e1.HE 
  ,e1.HJ 
  ,e1.HK 
  ,e1.GW 
  ,e1.DX 
  ,e1.DY 
  ,e1.DZ 
  ,e1.EA 
  ,e1.FM 
  ,e1.FN 
  ,e1.FS 
  ,e1.FV 
  ,e1.FU 
  ,e1.FW 
  ,e1.YP 
  ,e1.FT 
  ,e1.FY 
  ,e1.FZ 
  ,e1.FO 
  ,e1.FX 
  ,e1.BV 
  ,e1.BX 
  ,e1.BZ 
  ,e1.CB 
  ,e1.CD 
  ,e1.CF 
  ,e1.BW 
  ,e1.BY1 
  ,e1.CA 
  ,e1.CC 
  ,e1.CE 
  ,e1.CG 
  ,e1.DI 
  ,e1.KC 
  ,e1.KF 
  ,e1.LP 
  ,e1.MY 
  ,e1.NC 
  ,e1.CO 
  ,e1.AB 
  ,e1.AD 
  ,e1.AF 
  ,e1.AH 
  ,e1.AJ 
  ,e1.AL 
  ,e1.FJ 
  ,e1.BL 
  ,e1.BN 
  ,e1.BP 
  ,e1.BR 
  ,e1.BT 
  ,e1.BO 
  ,e1.BQ 
  ,e1.BS 
  ,e1.GE 
  ,e1.DW 
  ,e1.FC 
  ,e1.HN 
  ,e1.BM 
 ,e2.secteur 
  ,e2.NAF2 
  ,e2.region 
  ,e2.departement 
  ,e2.siret 
  ,e1.designation 
  ,e2.effectif 
  ,e2.chiffre_affaire 
,e1.BU 
  ,e1.YY 
  ,e1.YZ 
  ,e1.siren 
  ,e1.AC 
  ,e1.AE 
  ,e1.AI 
  ,e1.AK 
  ,e1.AM 
  ,e1.CS 
  ,e1.CT 
  ,e1.CU 
  ,e1.CV 
  ,e1.BB 
  ,e1.BC 
  ,e1.BD 
  ,e1.BE 
  ,e1.BF 
  ,e1.BG 
  ,e1.BH 
  ,e1.BI 
  ,e1.1A 
  ,e1.GJ 
  ,e1.DA 
  ,e1.DC 
  ,e1.EK 
  ,e1.DD 
  ,e1.DE 
  ,e1.DF 
  ,e1.B1 

,e1.DG 
  ,e1.EJ 
  ,e1.DH 
  ,e1.DJ 
  ,e1.DK 
  ,e1.DM 
  ,e1.DN 
  ,e1.DP 
  ,e1.DQ 
  ,e1.EI 
  ,e1.FA 
  ,e1.FB 
  ,e1.FD 
  ,e1.FE 
  ,e1.FF 
  ,e1.FG 
  ,e1.FH 
  ,e1.FI 
  ,e1.FK 
  ,e1.FQ 
  ,e1.FR 
  ,e1.FWbis 
  ,e1.GF 
  ,e1.GG 
  ,e1.GH 
  ,e1.GI 
  ,e1.GJ1 
  ,e1.GK 
  ,e1.GL 
  ,e1.GN 
  ,e1.GO 
  ,e1.GP 
  ,e1.GS 
  ,e1.GT 
  ,e1.GV 
  ,e1.HB 
  ,e1.HC 
  ,e1.HD 
  ,e1.HF 
  ,e1.HG 
  ,e1.HH 
  ,e1.HI 
  ,e1.HL 
  ,e1.HM 
  ,e1.EQ 
  ,e1.DB 
  ,e1.AG 
  ,e1.EB1 

FROM bilan e1 JOIN data e2
WHERE e1.siren = e2.siren

");

            string serverIp = "127.0.0.1";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "root";
            string databaseName = "altares";

            string dbConnectionString = string.Format("server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};SslMode=none;Connect Timeout=600", serverIp, username, password, databaseName);

            var conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(MergeTables, conn);

            cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();

            Delete_Tables_Bilan_Data();

            MessageBox.Show("Table exercices now with data !!");

        }
```

Anyone have idea how to make this join more faster because it takes more than 10 minutes ???

Comment: Can you simplify your question so it is easier to read for us?

Comment: Do you have indexes for Siren on both tables? Also try wrapping in a transaction - BTW 90,000 isn't considered large.

Comment: Like always: QUery plan. Your insert does something in the select part that takes ages, find out what. Missing indices.

Comment: Did you try moving this part to SP and execute, it will execute faster.

Comment: @user3501749 It will. Possibly multiple uses possibly save 1/1000 of a second parsing text. On a 10 minute runtime. BAD. One statement is as fast as it gets. Particularly for large/slow statemnts that are not single line inserts.

Comment: @CetinBasoz in the two tables i have Siren as a column not an index ?

Comment: @TomTom didn't understand your solution ?

Comment: Yes they are columns, but do you have indexes for those columns? Otherwise a Join would take ages to complete (BTW for Join you would use ON ... - I think you made a typo while writing here).

Comment: @CetinBasoz  I don't have indexes for those columns so i create an indexes ?

Comment: Yes, create the indexes. Than it should execute in a second for 90K rows (might vary with your hardware).

Comment: @CetinBasoz  thank you for your help it's working now !!

Comment: @mecab95 Indices are standard in SQL. Read up at https://use-the-index-luke.com/ - always a good starting site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ludovic Feltz has answered the same, but I'll try to be more specific:

You will not be able to speed up your basic `INSERT` much. What is taking time, is making the join in the `SELECT` statement. Joins on columns that are not indexed are very slow. To speed it up, you need to put an index on e1.siren and e2.siren.

Answer (score -1):

The `JOIN` must use a `ON` clause and not a `WHERE`. Replace:

```
FROM bilan e1 JOIN data e2
WHERE e1.siren = e2.siren
```

By

```
FROM bilan e1 JOIN data e2 ON e1.siren = e2.siren
```

Then check if you correctly indexed your column `siren` in each table

Comment: No, he does not. It is new syntax and yes, it looks nicer, but he does not "MUST" do it - the old syntax works identical from a query optimizaton point of view.

Comment: @TomTom Ok did not know about that, thank you. But the second point is still valid